# What's the best way to get from Madrid Airport to Sevilla?

Tags: transit, airports, madrid, seville

I've heard of taking the AVE train, but wouldn't I have to somehow get from the MAD airport to the train station?

I am looking for a fast but safe route (I'm not sure how safe the public/city buses are but I am going to have all my travel bags and will look like a huge, foreign target). If possible, I'd like to save money. My flight lands at 1, and I have about 4.5 hours to get from Madrid to Seville, and I have to be in a place called the "Hotel Alcazar" which is about a 10-minute walk from the Seville Cathedral.

Can someone give me the least stressful way to get there? I was thinking maybe just taxi to the AVE, then get off in Sevilla and walk but if there's another great train that's fast that I don't know about please suggest!

Comment: Take a look at [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/) for options. As @pnuts suggests, flying may be the best, least stressful option.

Comment: why the 4.5 hours time restriction to get to Sevilla ?

Answer (score 4):

There's the **C1** train that goes from Barajas' Terminal 4 to Atocha.

I don't know if this is still vald, but if you already have your AVE train ticket, then you get a free pass on the C1:

http://www.accesrail.com/pdf/MAD-airport.pdf

This would be the simplest and cheaper way to do it.

From Atocha, take the AVE to Sevilla.

Comment: I missed that part.

Answer (score 4):

The AVE seems around [$66 and 2-1/2 hours](https://www.raileurope.com/en/us/point_to_point/ptp_results.htm?execution=e1s1&resultId=140676230&cobrand=public&saleCountry=us&resultId=140676230&cobrand=public&saleCountry=us&itemId=-1&fn=fsRequest&cobrand=public&c=USD&roundtrip=0&isAtocRequest=0&georequest=1&lang=en&route-type=0&from0=Madrid&to0=Seville&deptDate0=11%2F30%2F2016&time0=14&time1=8&pass-question-radio=1&p=0&nA=1&nY=0&nC=0&nS=0). Flights seem to start at around $43 and 1 hour, though timings might not suit.